# Converting large Int from String

Tags: swift, string, int, 32bit-64bit

What seems to be something that should be fairly trivial has been causing me quite a bit of issues. I am attempting to convert a large integer to the Int type from a String. Basically I have a 64 bit hash that at one point gets passed around as a String and I need to convert it back to an Int.

According to all documentation I could find, in Swift the Int type is 64bits. Calling, Int(str) should handle 64bit conversions just fine. But it seems that it's trying to convert it to a 32bit integer so I receive a nil value. I'm unable to use Int64() for various reasons (long story short the key in my hash table has to be of type Int not Int64).

Here is what the code looks like:

Declared at the start of the class:

```
var nameTable: Dictionary<Int, String> = [:]
```

Declared later in some function:

```
let kv = data[i].componentsSeparatedByString(":")
self.nameTable[Int(kv[0])!] = kv[1]
```

Where `kv[0]="3928953869951869841"` and `kv[1]="a"` the piece `Int(kv([0])!` fails because a nil value is returned when it was unexpected.

`Int.max` returns a value of 2147483647, the 32bit max int, which strikes me as odd considering all docs state int as a 64bit value. Code has been run on iPhones 5 - 6s, all with the same result.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: it is not a conversion problem probably your `kv[0]` value is nil

Comment: I was hoping that was the case, but printing out kv[0] gave me the value I placed there

Comment: can you share actual value? is it  `"3928953869951869841"`

Comment: Yes, though it varies each time the code is run. It's a value given to me from a hash I retrieve from an object.

Comment: Int is 32-bit on all 32-bit devices (e.g. iPhone 4, 5), and 64-bit on 64-bit devices (e.g. iPhone 5S, 6). So your code should work on a 64-bit device, but would fail on a 32-bit device.

Comment: @MartinR so inorder to support the iPhone 5, I would have to use Int64?

Comment: @MartinR Hm, okay that does make sense. What's odd is that the iPhone 5 seems to store the hash as a 64bit value just fine in Int when it pulls it. But I guess it would make sense if it's actually retrieving a 32bit hash.

Comment: The `hashValue()` returns  an `Int` and therefore is 32-bit or 64-bit. Note that it makes no sense to pass the hash value around, it is not stable between different invocations (and in particular dependent on the platform).

Answer (score 0):

Int("string") - is optional type
If you want to exclude nil exception, try this code:

```
    let stingNumber = "3928953869951869841"
    if let index = Int64("\(stingNumber)") {
        self.nameTable[index] = "a"
        NSLog("\(self.nameTable)")
        NSLog("\(Int64.max)")
    }
```

I was simulated this on iPhone 4s and i had log:

```
2016-08-10 15:22:24.199 stackoverlow-38866748[52907:1401199] [3928953869951869841: "a"] 
2016-08-10 15:22:24.202 stackoverlow-38866748[52907:1401199] 9223372036854775807
```

Answer (score 0):

See [`Int`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/Int) in 
the Apple Developer Documentation:

> On 32-bit platforms, `Int` is the same size as `Int32`, and on 64-bit platforms, `Int` is the same size as `Int64`.

`3928953869951869841` exceeds the range for 32-bit integers.
Therefore, in order to store that value in an integer, you *have* to
use `Int64` (or `UInt64`), there is no way around it (unless the app is restricted to 64-bit devices only).

Note also that the documentation for [`hashValue()`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/hashable/1540917-hashvalue) states:

> Hash values are not guaranteed to be equal across different executions of your program. Do not save hash values to use during a future execution.